# Pandas time period data type prints as numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe which contains dates which I converted to a pandas TimeSeries.

From there, I wanted to add a column to the DF which would be the same as the date column, just in Period format with frequency set to months.

The problem is, within the dataframe, the period column prints as numbers (2009-1 prints as 468, 2009-2 prints as 469, etc).

When I create a separate PeriodIndex object outside of the DF, this is not an issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Code I used to convert unformatted time column to DateTime:

```
subset['Created On'] = pd.to_datetime(subset['Created On'])
```

Code for creating column with Periods:

```
subset['Month'] = pd.PeriodIndex(subset['Created On'],freq='M')
```

Code that creates a separate PeriodIndex object and properly displays dates in month format:

```
months = pd.PeriodIndex(subset['Created On'],freq='M')
```

EDIT:

As requested in the comments, subset[:1].to_dict() outputs:

```
#[Out]# {'Created On': {12822544: <Timestamp: 2009-01-01 00:00:00>}, 'City': {12822544: 'BROOKLYN'}, 'Borough': {12822544: 'Unspecified'}, 'Location': {12822544: '(40.65662129596871, -73.95806621423951)'}, 'Closed Date': {12822544: '01/07/2009 12:00 AM'}}
```

Note that since my OP, I lost my session and had to re-upload the data to a DF. At this point, I've only converted the column 'Created On' to a timestamp using the pd.to_datetime method. Since then, I've tried using:

```
subset['Created On'].resample('M')
```

Which results in the error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Maybe a part of the issue is that I'm not using the date column as the DF index? If so, that wouldn't work well since it contains a ton of non-unique values and I'm already using a Unique ID field which is more representative of an index.

Comment: I think you want to `resample` your dataframe, but I'm not sure. Please give some example data and show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `df[:1].to_dict()`? Perhaps then we can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. As a temporary workaround, you can do:

```
subset['Month'] = pd.PeriodIndex(subset['Created On'],freq='M').asobject
```

http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2281

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much Wes. PS - your talks at PyData in NYC we're great--keep it up!

Comment: This works, but is VERY slow when working on large datasets (>1MM rows)...any speedier alternatives?